# time limit exceeded for algorithm question in Java "Number of Islands"

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

for leetcode 200 Number of Islands, this solution works fine. However, for the lower solution, the submission fails due to time limit exceeded. In my understanding, both solution should run in the same time. Would you please help on this?

```
class Solution {
    // BFS time O(mn) | space O(min(m,n))
    public int numIslands(char[][] grid) {
        int islandsCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
                    islandsCount++;
                    bfs(grid, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return islandsCount;
    }

    public static void bfs(char[][] grid, int row, int col) {
        int rc = grid.length;
        int cc = grid[0].length;
        Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        queue.offer(row*cc + col);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Integer spotIdx = queue.poll();
            int i = spotIdx/cc, j = spotIdx%cc;
            // grid[i][j] = '0';
            if (i-1 >= 0 && grid[i-1][j] == '1') {
                queue.offer((i-1)*cc+j);
                grid[i-1][j] = '0';
            }
            if (i+1 < rc && grid[i+1][j] == '1') {
                queue.offer((i+1)*cc+j);
                grid[i+1][j] = '0';
            }
            if (j-1 >= 0 && grid[i][j-1] == '1') {
                queue.offer(i*cc+(j-1));
                grid[i][j-1] = '0';
            }
            if (j+1 < cc && grid[i][j+1] == '1') {
                queue.offer(i*cc+(j+1));
                grid[i][j+1] = '0';
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The following version will throw time limit exceeded, but still give correct answer in some test cases.

```
class Solution {
    // BFS time O(mn) | space O(min(m,n))
    public int numIslands(char[][] grid) {
        int islandsCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
                    islandsCount++;
                    bfs(grid, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return islandsCount;
    }

    public static void bfs(char[][] grid, int row, int col) {
        int rc = grid.length;
        int cc = grid[0].length;
        Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        queue.offer(row*cc + col);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Integer spotIdx = queue.poll();
            int i = spotIdx/cc, j = spotIdx%cc;
            grid[i][j] = '0';
            if (i-1 >= 0 && grid[i-1][j] == '1') {
                queue.offer((i-1)*cc+j);
            }
            if (i+1 < rc && grid[i+1][j] == '1') {
                queue.offer((i+1)*cc+j);
            }
            if (j-1 >= 0 && grid[i][j-1] == '1') {
                queue.offer(i*cc+(j-1));
            }
            if (j+1 < cc && grid[i][j+1] == '1') {
                queue.offer(i*cc+(j+1));
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code marks grid elements as visited when they are **written to** the queue. The second code marks them as visited when they are **read from** the queue. So the problem is that in the second code, the same element can be written into the queue many times. The easy way to prove this is to add an `int q_count` variable that is incremented every time that `queue.offer` is called. Then print the count after the BFS finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this particular input:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

The first time `bfs` gets called, it gets 1 and 1 as values for `i` and `j`.

The queue receives the coordinates (1, 1) which it pulls again.

The cell is cleared, so we get:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

Then two of the four `if` conditions are true, and the queue receives coordinates (2, 1) and (1, 2).

In the second iteration, (2, 1) is popped from the queue, and the cell is cleared:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

Only one `if` condition is true and (2, 2) is pushing unto the queue, which now has (1, 2) and (2, 2).

Then in the third iteration (1, 2) is popped from the queue, and the cell is cleared:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

One `if` condition is true, and (2, 2) is pushed to the queue. But now we have (2, 2) twice on the queue!

So in the fourth iteration, (2, 2) is popped and cleared:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

No `if` condition is true.

The fifth iteration will pop (2, 2) again, but it was already cleared and processed, so this is a useless iteration.

This was just a simple example, but in bigger grids, the number of "duplicate" coordinates on the queue can quickly increase, and they all represent an iteration that will happen for ... nothing. It is a waste of time. Apparently the test suit includes cases where this will make your function run out of time because of this useless overhead.

The first version of your code will not allow a duplicate to get on the queue.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation is very clear~